# problem creating ubuntu 20.0 bootable usb disk, startup creator won't open, bootiso is frozen

Tags: live-usb

I have to install ubuntu on another machine, so I downloaded the iso from ubuntu web page and tried to follow the tutorial to create the bootable usb stick, but startup disk creator won't open in my ubuntu 18.04 machine, even though I removed and reinstalled it.

So I start searching for a cli alternative and found this tool:

```
curl -L https://git.io/bootiso -O
chmod +x bootiso
sudo apt install wimtools
```

I run it on my iso and selected the usb device and it's been like this all night:
[image: screenshot]

So, I want to know if I can kill this without killing my usb stick and if you can point out to an alternative it would be great. In the meantime I will keep looking.

Comment: Try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It works well with all versions of Ubuntu (including the developing version). -- If writing to your USB drive is extremely slow, it might help to 'wipe the whole device' (also using mkusb). After that you can expect to get a more responsive USB drive, and it should work well to install Ubuntu live into it by cloning.

Comment: And yes, you can kill the process without killing the USB drive's hardware (but the partition table and file system might be damaged). This will be fixed the next time you create a live operating system in the USB drive.

Comment: Another vote for **mkusb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Installing mkusb and dus

**Mkusb and dus** can also be installed to Persistent USB exactly the same as to an Installed drive:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mkusb
sudo apt install usb-pack-efi
```

**Version dus and guidus seperately**

```
sudo apt install dus
sudo apt install guidus
```

Ref:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=95&p=13961108#post13961108